# C# WPF ThreadPool

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, thread-safety

I am implementing a WPF application. In this app I have to manage different operations with Serial Ports. All this operations I want to do it in another thread but only one thread waiting for task and make a queue with all this tasks like a LooperThread in Java. I was thinking about the possibility to do a ThreadPool with only one thread size. Are there better possibilities? Thanks!

Comment: Look into the [`Task Parallel Library`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: With this library each time I create a task a have a new thread but I want only want thread working like a queue and do all the task.

Comment: Then create a single thread which runs an inner loop.

Comment: Just use the existing thread pool.  If one thread is capable of handling all of the work its given, then the pool will only create one thread.  If multiple threads are needed to get the work done, then multiple threads will be created.  Trust in the pool to sensibly manage the threads so you just don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

For threading the new model to use is the Task Parallel Library.
If you have a bunch of independent operations that need to happen maybe have a look at TPL Dataflows and set them up as a chain of operations.

http://www.michaelfcollins3.me/blog/2013/07/18/introduction-to-the-tpl-dataflow-framework.html

[image]